# Execute PHP page (that have some JS code) from another PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I know this sound a bit weird, I will explain: I have a PHP with several processes, let call this file "main.php"

I have another file PHP that executes a file manager written in PHP and a text processor written in `JavaScript` (I must do this in JavaScript, I can't change this language or port it to server side), this PHP take some seconds (can be few minutes) to finish the process and creates new files on the server. This process is in http://localhost/processor/

I want to run the main.php and at specific point (`Synchronous` execution of the code) run the http://localhost/processor/

Example of main.php:

```
<?php
print "one";
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/processor/index.php');
print "three";
?>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Solve what problem? What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: require\include will bring all the code from index.php in to main.php, is that what you want?

Comment: The problem is that is not working, its don't generate the proccesed files on the server.

Comment: code you haven't shown us, is not doing something you vaguely describe - not sure what kind of miracle workers you think we are.

Comment: @nogad require/include can execute the page like I can do it from Mozilla Firefox (i.e) - If I open manually http://localhost/processor/ the files are created, but via required/included they are not

Comment: turn on error reporting .. just add ` error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); ` to the top of your script

Comment: Have you tried to use testing tool, like codeception? it involves running browser (or browser-like program) in the background, but seems to me like most reliable way of executing JS inside PHP.

Comment: @DuaneLortie do it, no errors, main.php finish the execution too fast, it should take 30 seconds aproximatelly, because right now that is the time took by processor

Comment: you mean you want to delay the code? like use the php sleep()?

Comment: @Zaper127 honestly I don't think `sleep` can help